# Which emulator I can use for Install Ubuntu phone and Android dual boot virtually?

Tags: dual-boot, virtualbox, emulation, ubuntu-emulator

I do not have any smartphone. But I want to use and test Ubuntu Phone virtually.
 And also in that virtual device I want try to install **triple boot system**. That means I want emulator in which I can install
***Windows phone* + *Android* + *Ubuntu mobile*.**

So I want to know:-

1. Emulator for Ubuntu phone OS
2. Emulator for Windows Phone OS
3. Emulator in which I can install all/multiple Mobile OS and test it.

**Note**:
I use Genymotion, blue-stack for Android emulator.
And Virtual box on Linux and VM_ware on windows OS for normal PC visualization.
*In my virtual PC I successfully install dual Boot computer based OS and normally Run and use it. [Linux + Windows]*